# Can I include OpenWRT's Unified Configuration Interface (UCI) as part of a Yocto build?

Tags: yocto, openwrt, uci

We have a Yocto build system targeting a number of ARM-based router type devices.

It sure would be nice to include OpenWrt's Unified Configuration Interface (UCI), so that our configurations scripts don't have to be constantly messing with config files in /etc.

Does anyone have experience doing that? Is UCI something that can be pulled cleanly into a non-OpenWrt embedded Linux system? Or is it tied to other aspects of OpenWrt?

I saw one set of instructions for adding UCI to Ubuntu, so I guess this should also be doable.

Thanks!